# Typescript function overload with optional param and rest params

Tags: typescript

I have a function in Typescript with overloads as follows:

```
function test(atts?: {[key: string]: string}, ...children: string[]): void;
function test(atts?: {[key: string]: string}): void;
function test(...children: string[]): void; //Overload 3
function test(): void;
function test(arg1?: {[key: string]: string} | string[], ...arg2: string[]) {
  console.log(arg1, arg2)
}
```

However, I keep being told that overload 3 is not compatible with it's implementation signature. How do I fix this error?

I've looked at other answers, but am still struggling to make this work. I think it has something to do with arg2 being potentially undefined, which makes it incompatible with the third overload. But rest parameters can't be undefined, so I'm not sure how to implement this logic if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect `arg1` in the implementation to possibly be a *`string`*, not a `string[]`, right?  The third call signature supports something like `test("hey", "you", "there")`... in which case, `arg1` will be `"hey"` and `arg2` will be `["you", "there"]`.

But you have `arg1` as possibly `string[]`, which is not possible.  So there's the error.  Change it to `string` and it should work:

```
function test(atts?: {[key: string]: string}, ...children: string[]): void;
function test(atts?: {[key: string]: string}): void;
function test(...children: string[]): void; 
function test(): void;
function test(arg1?: {[key: string]: string} | string, ...arg2: string[]) {
// ------------------------------------------> ~~~~~~ <--- here
  console.log(arg1, arg2)
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgIZSmgfgC5EBvAbQGsUBPEjAJxjAHMBdeqJ1gXwBpEAOmEQAFjAA2AEwYownbi3JsAlCQBucGFIDcAKFCRYCZOiy58xMlVoLm7O7zWJN2-YejwkqDJmGCxSRk5RyVVDS1dRAB6aIB5dRQGCThsKUQAZgNwTxMfLGdXXWyjL1NfbAYWAEYrCmo6REZ7Diauex5EAB82xQF-SpYAJlDlFTI9REQIBDQ4CRRBFJYcKuqBQaGVPR4gA)

Comment: Oh gotcha! I see now. Thank you!